# fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value on physics contact

Tags: xcode, swift, game-physics, skphysicsbody

I can't seem to figure out which optional value it is talking about or why i am getting this error. I checked my score integer and made sure that I declared its value is 0 until it makes contact with the enemy. In the simulator the counter counts the first 4 or 5 enemies then crashes.

```
var score = Int? ()
var scoreLabel = UILabel ()
 override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

    scoreLabel.text = "\(score)"
    scoreLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 
    20))
    scoreLabel.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()

    score = nil
    if score == nil {
        score = 0
        scoreLabel.text = "\(score!)"
}
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

    let firstBody : SKPhysicsBody = contact.bodyA
    let secondBody : SKPhysicsBody = contact.bodyB

    if ((firstBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.bullet) &&  
(secondBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.enemy) ||
        (firstBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.enemy) && 
(secondBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.bullet)) {
 //i get the error next line            
collisionWithBullet((firstBody.node as! SKSpriteNode), 
bullet: (secondBody.node as! SKSpriteNode))
    }
}

func collisionWithBullet(enemy: SKSpriteNode, bullet: SKSpriteNode){

    score? += 1
    scoreLabel.text = "\(score!)"
    enemy.removeFromParent ()
    bullet.removeFromParent ()

}
```

Comment: Objective c, it would be `[enemy removeFromParent]`

Comment: Start logging up the chain then. Does collisionWithBullet get called? If so, what is enemy and what is bullet when it's called?

Comment: Why do you declare `score` as optional? If the initial value is 0 anyway declare it as non-optional `var score = 0`

Comment: @vadian i tried making it a variable and deleted the if score = nil, i get the same error on the same line. if you have any other ideas please let me know

Answer (score 2):

make score as non optional and set 0 as default score

```
var score = 0
var scoreLabel = UILabel ()

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

scoreLabel.text = "\(score)"
scoreLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 
20))
scoreLabel.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
```

// assigning nil to score and checking for nil ???

```
//score = nil
//if score == nil {
 //   score = 0
 //  scoreLabel.text = "\(score!)"
//}

score = 0
scoreLabel.text = "\(score!)"

func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

let firstBody : SKPhysicsBody = contact.bodyA
let secondBody : SKPhysicsBody = contact.bodyB

if ((firstBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.bullet) &&  
(secondBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.enemy) ||
    (firstBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.enemy) && 
(secondBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.bullet)) {
//i get the error next line            
collisionWithBullet((firstBody.node as! SKSpriteNode), 
bullet: (secondBody.node as! SKSpriteNode))
}
}

func collisionWithBullet(enemy: SKSpriteNode, bullet: SKSpriteNode){

score += 1 // score is no more optional. default score is 0
scoreLabel.text = "\(score!)"
enemy.removeFromParent ()
bullet.removeFromParent ()

}
```

Comment: thanks for the help, I changed my integer to a variable but i still get the error and i can no longer apply a ! to score. and set the default score to 0 in the move to view.

Comment: also deleted the score = nil if score == nil { score = 0 scoreLabel.text = "(score!)" } my theory behind that was to create a nil value so that when the optional is found nil while being unwrapped the app won't crash because it has a nil value @jess